# Racket, split a list in two different size lists

Tags: racket

This code splits a list in two equal size lists:

```
(define (split ls)
  (if (or (null? ls) (null? (cdr ls)))
      (list ls '())
      (let ((next (split (cddr ls))))
        (list (cons (car ls) (car next))
              (cons (cadr ls) (cadr next))))))
```

I would like to build a code (define (split size ls)) where size has a value, for example: 0.20, 0.50, 0.63 and it is the number (in %) that will go to the first list.

Comment: Is it important that the splitting be in a deterministic, alternating order as it is in `split`? Are there any requirements for how the function rounds the number when it can't be achieved exactly?

Comment: No, it is not important how to round the number when it can't be achieved exactly. Now that I have the example of spliting keeping the order I would like another example were the elements are send to each list randomly. So the resulting two list will always be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

Instead of using the helper function `split-at` one could use your function `split`.

```
#lang racket

; clamp : number number -> number
;   make sure x is in the interval [a;b],
;   if not return a or b.
(define (clamp x a b)
  (max (min x b) a))


; split-list : number list -> list list
;   return two values:
;     - appending the two lists will produce the a list equal to the input list xs
(define (split-list pct xs)
  ; find the position to split the list
  (define pos (exact-round (* (clamp pct 0.0 1.0) (length xs))))
  ; split it
  (split-at xs pos))

(split-list 0.00 '(a b c d))
(split-list 0.25 '(a b c d))
(split-list 0.50 '(a b c d))
(split-list 0.75 '(a b c d))
(split-list 1.00 '(a b c d))
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Now that I have the example of spliting keeping the order I would like another example were the elements are send to each list randomly. So the resulting two lists will always be different. Please, could you help?

Comment: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=shuffle#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._shuffle%29%29